# Install Node libraries in private github repos during CI

Tags: node.js, heroku, github, npm, continuous-integration

I have a private repository on Github set up with Heroku CI. This project uses a few libraries that I also have in private repos on Github and install with yarn. These libraries break my Heroku CI because they require logging in to Github to install during the tests and builds. I know you can generate a key for libraries on NPM and throw it in your .npmrc, but I don't know if there is a way to do it for private Github repos that I have seen.